# How to show the identifier on the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used react.js to connect the api.

And i want to show the identifier on the page.

Here is response to console.log(this.state.weathers.cwbopendata)

[image]

After i console.log(this.state.weathers.cwbopendata.identifier)
,I got the error
[image]
What should i do to show the identifier on the page?

Here is the code:

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react';

 class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
     this.state = {
       weathers: {},
     };
   }
  componentDidMount(){
      fetch('https://opendata.cwb.gov.tw/fileapi/v1/opendataapi/F-C0032-001?Authorization=CWB-BB78764B-9687-4C1C-B180-66CB616129E5&format=JSON')
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then( JSON=> this.setState({weathers:JSON}))
   }

   render(){
      return (
         <div className="App">

          {console.log(this.state.weathers.cwbopendata.identifier)} 
         </div>

    );
   }
  }

 export default App;
```

Comment: During the first render `this.state.weathers.cwbopendata` is undefined - the first console statement shows as much, and the error explains the same. You need to ensure there's a value before attempt to access `.identifier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic problem many newcomers face. You need to add a state to let your component know that data fetching is **in progress**, **is completed** or **there is an error**. So the component can show real data when it successfully fetched it, until then something you can display to the UI to let users know that the App is fetching data... I'd write it something like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      weathers: {},
      isFetching: true
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "https://opendata.cwb.gov.tw/fileapi/v1/opendataapi/F-C0032-001?Authorization=CWB-BB78764B-9687-4C1C-B180-66CB616129E5&format=JSON"
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ weathers: json, isFetching: false }));
  }

  render() {
    const { isFetching, weathers } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {isFetching ? "Loading.." : weathers.cwbopendata.identifier}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In your case you tried to render the data at first mount, and at this point of time `weathers` is just holding an empty object `{}`. Thus `weathers.cwbopendata` returns `undefined`, and `undefined.identifier` throws the error as you see in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Initially `render` method is being called before `componentDidMount`.

By the time it was called, data hadn't been fetched yet.

So you should properly handle situation when you have empty state.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';

 class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
     this.state = {
       weathers: {},
     };
   }
  componentDidMount(){
      fetch('https://opendata.cwb.gov.tw/fileapi/v1/opendataapi/F-C0032-001?Authorization=CWB-BB78764B-9687-4C1C-B180-66CB616129E5&format=JSON')
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then( JSON=> this.setState({weathers:JSON}))
   }

   render(){
      return (
         <div className="App">

          {console.log(this.state.weathers.cwbopendata && this.state.weathers.cwbopendata.identifier)} 
         </div>

    );
   }
  }

 export default App;
```